# javascript regex test() function gives always true

Tags: javascript, jquery

In javascript i am using the following regular expression to check whether the input string is 6 characters long and it should contains only alphabets and digits,

```
var name = "a";
if(/[0-9a-zA-Z]{6,}/.test(name))
{  }
```

But this gives always true. Whats the problem ?

Comment: That regex will match any string that **contains** at least 6 such characters (in sequence). *edit* However, for the string "a", it definitely will return `false`.

Comment: Seems to work just fine.  I tested your exact code above and it gave false on short strings or string with other characters, and true if 6 or more characters that match the regex

Comment: Works fine for me. But yes, your current code says *at least* 6 characters, not exactly 6. Change `6,` to `6`.

Comment: Your code doesn't return `true`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

{6,} means at least 6 characters long. If you want 6 exactly.
Go for {6}.